# How to get a method outline with ace

Tags: ace-editor

Does anyone know if it is possible to get an outline or a list of tags for an opened document with ace, like you could get for example with ctags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i've found a solution: You can call `editor.session.getTokens(0)` to get all tokens of the tokeniser for the current session.

For each token, you get the following information:

```
index: 2
start: 9
type: "entity.name.function"
value: "foo"
```

With this, you can easily create an outline